# Why do I need to read STDIN in gitolite hook

Tags: git, gitolite

When I ran git push to origin, sometimes I got the error as below:
`error: git-shell died of signal 13`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`
If tried again, it succeeded, but do not know the reason. Anyone can shed some lights?

BTW, I copy the `post-receive.mirrorpush` hook from [here](https://github.com/ellysh/gitolite/blob/master/hooks/common/post-receive.mirrorpush)
, where mentioned:
`# flush STDIN coming from git; we have no use for that info in this hook but`
`# if you don't do this, git-shell sometimes dies of a signal 13 (SIGPIPE)`
`[ -t 0 ] || cat >/dev/null`

Shall I read STDIN in `pre-receive` and `post-receive` hooks to avoid this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What gitolite version are you using? The hook you reference is from a very old Gitolite V2.x. I don't find any trace of `/dev/null` being used in this way in the latest sources of gitolite V3.x.

Comment: @VonC, It is V2.x. I am not using V3.

Comment: I understand. any chance to see if the issue persists with a gitolite V3?

Comment: My red-hat version does not support V3. Seems the error happens randomly, if I try again, it would disappear.

Comment: You can simply clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/, and install it from there (in a different path, in order to not mess with your current setup). That would make a gitolite V3.5.x.

Answer (score 1):

Any post-receive or pre-receive hook in any language may see this error.  This has nothing to do with gitolite, except that v2 apparently uses post-receive hook to implement mirroring.  V3 does not use those git hooks.

It is not clear from OP whether he is using mirroring or he has his own post-receive hook and he was using that code as an example of "is this what is happening?"